# PlaceAutocomplete not working with setBoundsBias

Tags: android, google-places-api

I use PlaceAutocomplete with setBoundsBias to limit the city address more accurately, but when I input the Autocomplete does not work with the boundsbias that I have set.

Please help me, thanks!

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(15.924677, 108.335373), new LatLng(16.218292, 107.821762));
AutocompleteFilter filter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setCountry("VN")
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build();
try {
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .setBoundsBias(latLngBounds)
                    .setFilter(filter)
                    .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
        } catch () {
        }
```

Comment: Add code snippet that you have tried so far..

Comment: I added code!, please see where is the error